# When I change the size of an image with an slider the image moves

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uislider

I have an imageview that I can drag around the screen, I added a slider to change the imageview size and it works, but when I change the size the imageview allways returns to the original position, and it is no longer in the place where I dragged it, what could be wrong? this is my code for changing the size

```
- (IBAction)sizePhoto:(UISlider *)sender {
[_imagen1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.value, sender.value)];}
```

this is how I drag the image

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:_photo];

recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:_photo];
```

and this is how I rotate the image

```
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
recognizer.rotation = 0;
```

Comment: Do you change it's position by setting a translation transform?

Comment: Yes, using a handlePan

Comment: So sure, that scale transform _replaces_ the view's transform.  You'll want to combine them (or translate using layout constraints or frame).

Comment: How can I combine them? I will edit the question to add how I drag and rotate the image

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to combine the current transform with the change, so it preserves what the user has done already.  You do this correctly on the rotation.  Do it the same way with scale:

```
_imagen1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_imagen1.transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
```

Comment: I replaced the scale factor with sender.value, bur now the image is changing size but is not working well, it disappears...

Answer (score 0):

```
// pass your slider value: below code


 CGFloat scale = slider.value;
 CGAffineTransform theTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
  myImageView.transform = theTransform;
```